# Returning an std::optional<T> without copying

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

I'm currently learning OpenGL and while writing a shader abstraction class I chose [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) for error handling. Now to prevent accidental double freeing, I'm removing the copy constructors with

```cpp
// Shader.h
Shader(const Shader&) = delete;
Shader& operator=(const Shader&) = delete;
```

but when returning

```cpp
// Shader.cpp
return std::make_optional<Shader>(Shader(id));
```

in the static function `fromSrc` it gives me a compile error

```
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::make_optional" matches the argument list   LearnOpengl *\LearnOpengl\LearnOpengl\src\util\Shader.cpp   90
```

*I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (MSVC v143) with c++17*

Edit: I was told to implement a move constructor, is this a good implementation?

```cpp
    Shader::Shader(Shader&& other) noexcept
        : m_Id(std::exchange(other.m_Id, 0)), 
        m_Destroyed(std::exchange(other.m_Destroyed, true)), 
        m_Uniforms(std::exchange(other.m_Uniforms, {})) {}

    Shader& Shader::operator=(Shader other) noexcept {
        std::swap(m_Id, other.m_Id);
        std::swap(m_Destroyed, other.m_Destroyed);
        std::swap(m_Uniforms, other.m_Uniforms);
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: Have you implemented move ctors? You should also just write `std::make_optional<Shader>(id);`

Answer (score 6):

Making your wrappers non-copyable is good, but making them non-movable is a dead end.

The copy&swap idiom makes writing the move operations a no-brainer:

```
class Shader
{
    struct Data
    {
        int handle = 0; // For example.
        // More fields here, if needed.
        // You can get rid of the struct if there's only one. But if you do, make sure you use the same default value in the field initializer and in `std::exchange()` below.
    };
    Data data;

  public:
    Shader() {}
    // More constructors here.
   
    Shader(Shader &&other) noexcept : data(std::exchange(other.data, {})) {}
    Shader &operator=(Shader other) noexcept {std::swap(data, other.data); return *this;}

    ~Shader() {/* write me */}
};
```

You no longer need to manually delete the copy operations, since implementing the move operations does that automatically.